# Terminating duplicate processes with C#

Tags: c#, .net

So at the beginning of my program I have a piece of code that checks to see if another instance of this process is running.

```
Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
bool isProcessRunning = (Process.GetProcessesByName(process.ProcessName)).Length > 1;
```

If the the process is running then I open a message box that says the process is already running and asks the user if they want to terminate the current process and open a new one.

If the dialog result is yes then I use process.kill to close the process. The problem is I will have two of these processes running, so how do I specify which one to close? The process name will be exactly the same, and I want to close the one that was opened first.

Comment: you can try inter-process communication so that your processes close themselves

Comment: be a little more gentle than `Process.Kill()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the processes with the same name and check if the Id is different. If it is, kill it.

```
Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
var dupl = (Process.GetProcessesByName(process.ProcessName));
if( dupl.Length > 1 && MessageBox.Show("Kill?", "Kill duplicates?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes ) {
    foreach( var p in dupl ) {
        if( p.Id != process.Id )
            p.Kill();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
private static void killps(string processName)
{
    Process[] process = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
    Process current = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    foreach (Process p in process)
    {
        if (p.Id != current.Id)
        p.Kill();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to kill the process that is currently starting. The count will be 2 based on program path location and it will be terminated:

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)).Count() > 1) System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

You can also use the:

```
Process.Id
```

after you get your current Process using GetProcessesByName to difference processes.

Comment: Use the process.ID then once you GetProcessesByName() and compare it with the other running processes that have the same name

Answer (score 0):

You can use Process.StartTime property and see what process is started later and then kill it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this a little while ago using some R&D(Ripoff and Deploy) from another question and answer on this site (can't find the original), it checks to see if the program is already running from the same path (this allows multiple instances as long as the exe was launched from a different path). I make the other program the active window (it even restores the window it if it was minimized) and never even tell the user that there was a duplicate instance opened.

```
public static class SingleApplication
{
    [DllImport("user32.Dll")]
    private static extern int EnumWindows(EnumWinCallBack callBackFunc, int lParam);

    [DllImport("User32.Dll")]
    private static extern void GetWindowText(int hWnd, StringBuilder str, int nMaxCount);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetForegroundWindow")]
    private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern Boolean ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);

    static Mutex mutex;
    const int SW_RESTORE = 9;
    static string sTitle;
    static IntPtr windowHandle;
    delegate bool EnumWinCallBack(int hwnd, int lParam);

    private static bool EnumWindowCallBack(int hwnd, int lParam)
    {
        windowHandle = (IntPtr)hwnd;
        StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder(256);
        GetWindowText((int)windowHandle, sbuilder, sbuilder.Capacity);
        string strTitle = sbuilder.ToString();
        if (strTitle == sTitle && hwnd != lParam)
        {
            ShowWindow(windowHandle, SW_RESTORE);
            SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a form application. If another instance already running on the system activate previous one.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="frmMain">main form</param>
    /// <returns>true if no previous instance is running</returns>
    public static bool Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form frmMain)
    {
        if (IsAlreadyRunning())
        {
            sTitle = frmMain.Text;
            EnumWindows(new EnumWinCallBack(EnumWindowCallBack), frmMain.Handle.ToInt32());
            return false;
        }
        Application.Run(frmMain);
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks using a Mutex with the name of the running assembly's location
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True if the assembly is already launched from the same location, false otherwise.</returns>
    private static bool IsAlreadyRunning()
    {
        string strLoc = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;

        FileSystemInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(strLoc);
        string name = fileInfo.Name;
        mutex = new Mutex(true, name);
        if (mutex.WaitOne(0, false))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

It is used as the following

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        SingleApplication.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

If you wanted to, you could check if `true` or `false` that is returned from `SingleApplication.Run()` to find out if your program is starting or not. It blocks until `Application.Run()` would normally exit and returns true, or it immediately returns false if the program was already running.

Answer (score 0):

By comparing the start time of both processes.

```
 Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
 Process [] duplicateProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName(process.ProcessName).ToArray();
 if (duplicateProcess.Length > 1)
 { 
        if (MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Found. Do you want to kill duplicate process", "Duplicate Process", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            foreach (Process p in duplicateProcess)
            {
                int res = DateTime.Compare(p.StartTime, process.StartTime);
                if (res < 0)
                {
                    // P process opened first
                    p.Kill();
                }
                else if ( res > 0 )
                {
                    // process Opened first
                    process.Kill();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```